# How write correct condition? (FEN chess)

Tags: python, dictionary, chess

I'm trying to build a simple chess game in python, I've created a dictionary with positions on the pawns. I want to change dictionary into [Forsyth–Edwards Notation (FEN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) (the position of the pawns).

```
curr_position = {'a8': 'r', 'b8': 'n', 'c8': 'b', 'd8': 'q', 'e8': 'k', 'f8': 'b', 'g8': 'n', 'h8': 'r', 'a7': 'p', 'b7': 'p', 'c7': 'p', 'd7': 'p', 'e7': 'p', 'f7': 'p', 'g7': 'p', 'h7': 'p', 'a6': None, 'b6': None, 'c6': None, 'd6': None, 'e6': None, 'f6': None, 'g6': None, 'h6': None, 'a5': None, 'b5': None, 'c5': None, 'd5': None, 'e5': None, 'f5': None, 'g5': None, 'h5': None, 'a4': None, 'b4': None, 'c4': None, 'd4': None, 'e4': None, 'f4': None, 'g4': None, 'h4': None, 'a3': None, 'b3': None, 'c3': None, 'd3': None, 'e3': None, 'f3': None, 'g3': None, 'h3': None, 'a2': 'P', 'b2': 'P', 'c2': 'P', 'd2': 'P', 'e2': 'P', 'f2': 'P', 'g2': 'P', 'h2': 'P', 'a1': 'R', 'b1': 'N', 'c1': 'B', 'd1': 'Q', 'e1': 'K', 'f1': 'B', 'g1': 'N', 'h1': 'R'}
```

the above dictionary should return something like this in FEN:

```
"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"
```

I wrote

```
def curr_fen():
    positions2 = ""
    pos_temp = 0
    prev_value = 0
    for ix, value in enumerate(curr_position.values()):
        if ix % 8 == 0 and ix != 0:
            positions2 += "/"
            pos_temp = 0
        if not value:
            pos_temp += 1
            positions2 += str(pos_temp)
        else:
            positions2 += value
    return positions2

print(curr_fen())
```

which returns

```
"nbqkbnr/pppppppp/12345678/12345678/12345678/12345678/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"
```

which is incorrect. How can I adjust my function to return the desired output?

Comment: Have you debugged this? It seems like stepping though the code in a GUI debugger (like the really good free one in PyCharm) would shed light on why the code is giving that output, which should help you figure out what to fix. I think it's probably important that you debug the code before posting here, so that you can explain exactly what the code is doing versus what you want it to do.

Comment: We shouldn't have to go to an offsite resource to amswer your question. Your question should include a verbal description of the rules for the FEN format - it is OK to include a link but we shouldn't have to rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Fen a record contains 8th parts of the chessboard separated by "/"  which is responsible for one row in the board. You are starting from the top if you have a pawn on the field you are adding first letter of this pawn like "p" (small letters for white big for black) if the field is empty you are checking how many next is also empty and you are adding sum of it. For example, if you have in one row two pawn's in middle, record should look like this "/3pp3/" which means i have 3 empty field's two pawns and another 3 empty fields in one row.

Comment: use this https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you step through the board positions you are keeping track of consecutive empty *squares* with `pos_temp`.

The number of consecutive empty squares should be added to the string whenever you find a square with a piece or you move to the next rank (if the previous rank was completely empty).

`pos_temp` needs to be reset to zero whenever it is added to the string.

I've made some additions and one deletion to your code.

```
def curr_fen():
    positions2 = ""
    pos_temp = 0
    prev_value = 0
    for ix, value in enumerate(curr_position.values()):
        if ix % 8 == 0 and ix != 0:
            if pos_temp > 0:
                positions2 = positions2 + str(pos_temp)
            positions2 += "/"
            pos_temp = 0
        if not value:
            pos_temp += 1
            # positions2 += str(pos_temp)
        else:
            if pos_temp > 0:
                positions2 = positions2 + str(pos_temp)
                pos_temp = 0
            positions2 += value

    return positions2
```

---

Your solution relies on the dictionary being constructed in a specific order.  Here are a couple of alternatives that don't rely on the order of the original dictionary. They both have an intermediate step of transforming the original dictionary.

```
import collections
def f(d):
    rank_order = '87654321'
    file_order = 'abcdefgh'
    new = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for (file,rank),piece in d.items():
        new[rank].update({file:piece})
    board = []
    for rank in rank_order:
        s = ''
        temp = 0
        for file in file_order:
            piece = new[rank][file]
            if piece is None:
                temp += 1
            else:
                if temp > 0:
                    s = f'{s}{temp}'
                    temp = 0
                s = f'{s}{piece}'
        if temp > 0:
            s = f'{s}{temp}'
        board.append(s)
    return '/'.join(board)

import itertools
def g(d):
    rank_order = '87654321'
    file_order = 'abcdefgh'
    new1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for (file,rank),piece in d.items():
        new1[rank].append((file,piece))
    board = []
    for rank in rank_order:
        s = ''
        positions = new1[rank]
        positions.sort()
        for piece,items in itertools.groupby(positions,key=lambda x:x[1]):
            n_pieces = len(list(items))
            if piece is None:
                s = f'{s}{n_pieces}'
            else:
                s = f'{s}{piece * n_pieces}'
        board.append(s)
    return '/'.join(board)
```